# $locationChangeStart never broadcasted; $browser.onUrlChange never called after page load

Tags: angularjs

My angular app is non-standard in that we don't use route provider or UI router. WE use a durandal style of navigation that swaps out views using $http.

1. locationChangeStart never fires I think due to the fact that we are not changing our URL once in the SPA (though we plan to do so in the future sometimes). I can't test this, but if we remain in the SPA and we change the URL to point to a new view thru code (again, not using routeProvider/UiRouter) should I expect this event to fire?
2. My main issue is that I cannot handle these events: manual url change, back/forward/history buttons, external link clicks

I see $browser#onUrlChange is the function that broadcasts the $locationChangeStart event but that function only gets called on page load for me, but it seems to be exactly the code that should be getting called.

Documentation:

$browser#onUrlChange

- It's only called when the url is changed from outside of angular:
- user types different url into address bar
- user clicks on history (forward/back) button
- user clicks on a link

It's not called when url is changed by $browser.url() method

It says this part also:

- NOTE: this api is intended for use only by the $location service. Please use the {@link ng.$location $location service} to monitor url changes in angular apps.

I don't know how to 'use $location service to monitory url changes', so I am listening to the $locationChangeStart event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // Breakpoint hit here on page load only 
    var x = 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the onUrlChange/$locationChangeStart functions run for me?

thanks!